# Perl regex to match unbalanced token before line ends

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to match lines with unbalanced tokens before end of line (no nesting).

It is easy to match lines if token is a single character with `/{[^}]*$/`. It matches lines with open `{` like:

```
Some text {some text
```

And do not match terminated pairs on the same line like:

```
Some text {some} text
```

That's how it should work. But I am struggling to match unbalanced multicharacter tokens like `<a> </a>` or any `<blah> </blah>`.

Basically would need something similar to single char matching regex above replacing `[^}]*` to negation of multichar string before end of line anchor.
Experiments with negative lookahead or lookbehind like `|<a>.*(?!</a>).*$|` were not fruitful (naturally, as it seems if `(?!..)` is not strictly anchored then it will always find a place where this assertion is true, i.e. closing tag is not there hence it matches any line which has an open tag..

Intuitively I feel like missing something simple (or not) ?

Comment: Regular expressions are not good for balancing tokens, because they can't count.

Comment: @Barmar: Except that we are talking about Perl here, which support recursive regex and subroutine.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah, I agree, but I am trying to achieve something simpler as there is no nesting so it's enough to match an open tag before line ends.. Basically match any character except of closing tag is very simple, but how match anything except of substring (closing token) between open token and end of line anchor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do `'<a>(?!.*</a>)'`

The negative look-ahead `(?!.*</a>)` asserts that it is not possible to find `</a>` ahead in the string. The engine basically exhaust all possibility before concluding that it is not possible to find the pattern ahead in the string.

Comment: Yes, it works indeed. How could have I missed it :) Not saying that fully understand why it works.. but thanks!

Comment: I recall trying this pattern but anchored at the end of line, and that didn't worked: `<a>(?!.*</a>)$` (not matching any line). But without the anchoring it works fine. So there was a mistake...

Comment: @kastelian: When you are anchoring, you are asserting the open tag `<a>` is at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check that `</a>` is not there for every single character you process:

```
|<a>(?:(?!</a>).)*$|
```

You are right about

> `|<a>.*(?!</a>).*$|` [...] (naturally, as it seems if `(?!..)` is not strictly anchored then it will always find a place where this assertion is true

The first `.*` allow the engine to find some place where `</a>` can't be matched right after, can even be at the last `>` in `<a>text</a>`. (Actually, for this regex, the engine will match all the way to the end, since you can't match `</a>` at the end of the string anyway).

Comment: Thanks, the logic of lookahead assertions is not easy I must say.